# Java boolean return if statement

Tags: java, android, boolean, logic

Can someone please explain, in simple English, the logic behind this statement?

```
return mContainsLoadingRow ? (getContentDataSize() + 1) : getContentDataSize();
```

Assuming mContainsLoadingRow is a boolean, if `mContainsLoadingRow` is `true`,

then return `getContentDataSize() + 1`.

If not, return `getContentDataSize()`.

Is that the correct way to look at this?

Comment: Yes ist is. You can also write it as `if(mContainsLoadingRow ) return  getContentDataSize() + 1 else return getContentDataSize()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this complete expression is know as [**Ternary Operator**](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018)   in `Java`.

### Code Statement

```
mContainsLoadingRow ? (getContentDataSize() + 1) : getContentDataSize();
        ||                       ||                         ||
 //boolean expression      //return if true          //return if false
```

here in this code

`mContainsLoadingRow` is a Boolean variable which contains either `true` or `false`. you can also change `mContainsLoadingRow` with any Boolean expression like (a>b or b==a or b <= a etc.)

`? (question mark)` :- enables us to fine whether it is true or false.

if `true` the expression `(getContentDataSize() + 1)` will be return.

if `false` then  expressin `getContentDataSize()` value will be return.

Comment: Also a different way of writing this would be "return getContentDataSize()  + mContainsLoadingRow ? 1 : 0; "

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 0;
if (0 < 1){
  x = 2;
}else{
  x = 42;
}
// in short:
x = (0<1) ? 2 : 42;
```

So yes, you are right